# How would you make a !!say command for a discord bot?

Tags: java, bots, discord, discord-jda

This is how my commands are set up:

```
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent evt) {

    //Objects
    User objUser = evt.getAuthor();
    MessageChannel objMsgCh = evt.getChannel();
    Message objMsg = evt.getMessage();

    //Commands
    if(objMsg.getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase(Ref.prefix+"say " + message))
    {
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 1; i < command.length; i++) {
           if(i == command.length-1) {
               message.append(command[i]);
           }else {
               message.append(command[i] + " ");
           }
       }

    objMsgCh.sendMessage(message.toString()).queue();

    objMsg.delete();
    return;
    }
}
```

It doesn't reply with anything and I don't understand why.
I am using JDA (Java Discord API).

Comment: Doesn't seem like you even tried. All i see is an attempt at a `ping` command. Please show your attempt at implementing this, then explain the *specific* problem you're having while attempting to implement this.

Comment: Thanks for editing it to show an attempt. Currently, you are doing `equalsIgnoreCase(Ref.prefix+"say " + message)`. I'm not sure what the contents of `getContentRaw()`, but it seems easier to check if the content `startsWith(Ref.prefix + "say ")`, then parse out the `!!say` from the message if need be.

Comment: That still doesn't show how to make a `!!say` command work where the bot will copy what is said after the `!!say`

Answer (score 1):

Respect for your creativity but I think you are missing some basic java knowledge. Here is what I think you are aiming for:

```
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event){
    if(event.getMessage().getContentRaw().startsWith("!!say")){
        event.getChannel().sendMessage(event.getMessage().getContentRaw().substring(6)).queue();
        event.getMessage().delete().queue();
    }
}
```

I think the if condition is logical. Get the Messages as String in raw format and looking for the string starting with "!!say". Then send a new Message to the channel where the message was received where the message is the raw message as the string with the first five characters (the "!!say") are cut off. So the Bot is repeating the whole message beside the command tag.

Hope this brings you forward in your mission.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out how to do it.

`public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent evt) {`

```
//Objects
User objUser = evt.getAuthor();
MessageChannel objMsgCh = evt.getChannel();
Message objMsg = evt.getMessage();

if(objMsg.getContentRaw().startsWith(Ref.prefix+"say"))
{
    String words = objMsg.getContentRaw().substring(Ref.prefix.length() + 4);
    String more_words = words;
    objMsgCh.sendMessage(more_words).queue();
```

You don't really need `String more_words = words;`
And I do `(Ref.prefix.length() + 4)` so it says everything after !!say but make sure to make it create something like `String prefix = "!!";` because my may not be able to it with the prefix in the if statement. The `+ 4` counts every just after the prefix and the space between user input.
For Example:

`if(objMsg.getContentRaw().startsWith(Ref.prefix+"urban")) {
        String query = objMsg.getContentRaw().substring(Ref.prefix.length() + 6);`

Because `"urban"` has 5 characters you would put 6 to account for the space.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Doing `startsWith(Ref.prefix + "say")` is more costly than just `startsWith("!!say")`. If using a version of Java below 9, `Ref.prefix + "say"` will compile to `new StringBuilder(Ref.prefix).append("say")` (a new `StringBuilder` is instantiated, and a method is called). If you did `startsWith("!!say")`, then `"!!say"` will be *interned*, which means that same `String` object will be used each time you use that same literal. I recommend following the answer provided by @TimSchneider.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using the JDA-Utilities the following code will work for creating a command.

```
public class sayCommand extends Command {
public sayCommand() {
    this.help = "!say <message>";
    this.aliases = new String[] {"!s"};
    this.name = "say";
}

@Override
protected void execute(CommandEvent event) {
    event.getChannel().sendMessage(event.getMessage().getContentDisplay().split("\\s+", 2)[1]).queue();
}
```

}

With only using one line, you could have the bot easily mimic your argument.